# Adding element to jList in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlist

Using "test" rather than my string results to make less specific. Have checked other questions with this problem and have attempted but cannot find answer that works.

Trying to firstly print just "test" into my jList FriendsList which has been sent up through Netbeans. The model is default and I can't see anything wrong with the way I've set it up. The file is reading correctly as the System.out.

Java:

```
    DefaultListModel  listOfFriends;
    listOfFriends = new DefaultListModel();
    friendsList = new JList(listOfFriends);

    String[] result = line.split(","); // line is previously init.

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
         listOfFriends.addElement("test"); // THIS DOES NOT WORK
         System.out.println(result); // THIS WORKS
    }
```

The JList is added to the frame at the end of the file as Netbeans **automatically** does and then you cannot change it.

Java end of file (variables declaration which cannot be edited):

```
public javax.swing.JList<String> friendsList;
```

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character! Why does "FrindsList" start with an upper case character when none of your other variables do? Be consistent and follow Java conventions!

Comment: Do you add the JList to the frame? Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Note we don't have access to your data file, so first get it working with hard coded data. Once that works you just replace the hard code data with data from a file.

Comment: @camickr I've added them for you. The reason we set FriendsList with a capital is because we wanted to easily identify a swing element to something we've initialised. Just something that makes it easier for us coding and picking up on eachothers work. Thanks v much for your helpful comment though!

Comment: That does not make it easier. Java programmers know the Java conventions. Notice how the forum highlights the variable differently? The forum thinks the variable is a class name, since that is the Java convention. This makes your code difficult to read. If you want people to help then follow conventions.

Comment: @camickr Yep, noticed. Thanks for the heads up. I appreciate you educating me rather than down voting. Would you recommend any further editing to make users want to help?

Comment: I've already stated you need to post a proper [mcve]. If you add data to the model and the model to the JList and the JList to the JScrollPane and the JScrollPane to the JFrame, then the data will display. The code you posted does not show any of these steps. Until a problem is solved you don't know where the problem is so we need to see the context of how the code is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways of doing this:
1) In your code manually call list.setModel() anywhere after initComponents() is called. 2) Do it through NetBeans - Right click the list, go to "Customize Code". The first code section is the list's constructor call. Change the dropdown from "Default Code" to "Custom Creation" and simply insert your ListModel in the constructor call. You can do this by setting it to`new javax.swing.JList(new DefaultListModel())`
or by instantiating your listmodel before the call to initComponents() in the code and then doing
`javax.swing.JList(defaultModel);`

I just copied and pasted the code from a similar question answered by someone

Comment: Yes, you're correct, but even when one changes it from Abstract to DefaultListModel, it still doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: I guess you are trying to trying to add items to a JList dragged and dropped in the design tab through some other means rather than adding items in design tab.